# Add set of items to checklistbox and read values after

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

Is there any way to fill and get a `set` of items from a checklistbox?

What I did:

```
  TColorItem = (ms_red, ms_blue, ms_green, ms_yellow);
  TColorItems = set of TColorItem;
```

I have a component and I can choose from the `TColorItems`

```
 TProperty = class(TCollectionItem)
 private
   FModuleItem: TColorItems;  
   procedure SetColorItem(const Value: TColorItems);    
 published
   property ColorTypes: TColorItems read FColorItem write SetColorItem;

 procedure SetColorItem(const Value: TColorItems);
 begin
   FColorItem := Value;
 end;
```

After I setted up (checked) the items in the component, I created a form.

My form looks like this:

[image]

If I check any of the items from the checklistbox I want to get the `Result` as a `TColorItems` set:

- If **Red** and **Green** are checked the `set` must be

  `Result := [ms_red, ms_green]`
- If **Blue**, **Green** and **Yellow** are checked:

  `Result := [ms_blue, ms_green, ms_yellow]` etc..

The `Result` must be in this `[value1, value2]` form; I want to work with it after.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Declare an array of strings which pairs with the `TColorItem` type.

```
const
  ColorItemNames: array [TColorItem] of string = ('Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow');
```

Fill the `TCheckListBox` object with the array.

```
var
  ci: TColorItem;
begin
  for ci := Low(ColorItemNames) to High(ColorItemNames) do
    CheckListBox1.Items.AddObject(ColorItemNames[ci], TObject(ci));
end;
```

Get the values as a `TColorItems` from the `Objects` of the `TCheckListBox.Items` property.

```
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := [];
  for i := 0 to CheckListBox1.Count-1 do begin
    if CheckListBox1.Checked[i] then
      Include(Result, TColorItem(CheckListBox1.Items.Objects[i]));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: No kicking today ;) Good and complete

Comment: @TomBrunberg Thank you sir :)

Comment: @fantaghirocco I guess it should have been obvious but I never considered typecasting an enum to a TObject and back. Good tip.

Comment: @Dsm it scares me the same when typecasting `Integer` to `TObject` but it's a language feature indeed